# Sublime Text snippets in Ace Editor

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, ace-editor

Hey i know that we can use Sublime Texts .tmLanguage syntax in Ace Editor with the tools that comes with ace. Is it possible to even use Sublime Texts .sublime-snippet snippets in Ace Editor.

Answer (score 0):

In sublime's folder You can find snippets at `Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-completions`.
And then there is `ace/lib/ace/snippets`
 folder in Ace Editor. 
I haven't done it myself, but I am pretty sure that you can combine files in those folders. Have an experiment. :) 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

there is no automatic converter, but adding one is relatively straightforward,
parse xml of [sublime snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-3/extensibility/snippets.html) file and either keep it as json or as ace/snipmate [snippets](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/snippets.js#L530) file

```
var sublimeSnippet = plist.parse(xml)
var aceSnippet = ""
    + "snippet " + sublimeSnippet.tabTrigger
    + "description " + sublimeSnippet.description
    + "scope " + sublimeSnippet.scope.replace(/source\./g, "")
    + "\t" + sublimeSnippet.content.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\n\t")
    + "\n"
```